# Android Studio Edit Text - Keyboard doesn't appear in the App | Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I want to make a BMI-calculator app in Android Studio with Kotlin. Everything worked well, except the keyboard doesn't appear when i click on the edit text.

This is my Edit Text:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText
  android:id="@+id/et_weight"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  android:hint="weight in kilograms"
  />
```

I hope anyone can help me because i just don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you using `ExtractEditText`?

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:hint="weight in kilograms"/>
```